# Javascript Checking Keyboard State

Tags: javascript, dom-events, key-bindings

I am working on making a simple Javascript game and need to be able to check if certain keys are being pressed.  I have tried binding to the `onkeydown` event, but the problem that I am having is twofold: first, it won't let me check to see if more than one key is being pressed at any time. And second, it pauses after holding the key down before it starts spamming the event.

In my code, I could either have an event, or a function that checks every millisecond to see if the key is being pressed.  Seeing as this is a game, I would really have no problem with either.

Comment: Have you considered using a javascript library to take care of the binding? It would help you with dynamically setting keyup/keydown to ensure the game stays responsive.

Comment: I haven't seen any libraries that would deal with checking if the key is pressed or not.  I currently use jQuery, but I don't think that they have that functionality.  If you could suggest a library that does this, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use onkeydown and onkeyup together:

```
var pressed={};
element.onkeydown=function(e){
     e = e || window.event;
     pressed[e.keyCode] = true;
}

element.onkeyup=function(e){
     e = e || window.event;
     delete pressed[e.keyCode];
}
```

with this code you store every pressed key code in the `pressed` variable and then you delete it when the key is released. So when you need to know which keys are pressed you can loop with a for(..in..) through the pressed object.

Comment: If you hit [Alt/Ctrl]+[Tab] the 'keyup' of a key that has down won't  trigger. Avoid this behavior by adding 'blur' event: `window.addEventListener('blur',()=>pressed = {},false)`

Comment: there are still some edge cases this will miss. right-click on title bar of the browser, or the shortcuts menu or something...focus doesn't change, but key events are not sent.